# Elegant way to select multiple polylines to split/seperate them from the layer

Tags: modeling, uv-image-editor, select

I want to drape and image over my Model (square-like shape) but only the face surface and not the lateral surface. So I need to select the face surface polylines and split 'em from the lateral surfaces. What im doing for now is to "shift select" all polylines itself which is a huge fiddly work :/

My Question: Is there an elegant workflow to select the face surface in a faster and more easy way?

[image: SubsurfaceModel]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Knife Project` operation in this case.

Here is what you will do.

- Add a new `plane` object and place it wherever you want to select.
- Select your mesh and go to `edit mode`.
- Then select that `plane` by pressing `CTRL + LMB`
- In the last, press `F3` to search for the operation named `Knife Project`.
- Enter it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the awesome guide. But I guess I didnt described my problem clearly. I want the entire surface to be draped with the image. not only a square like u showed me with the plane.  Like this yellow marked area. If I hold and leftclick it also select the "side" surfaces so I need to zoom in and select each polyline by its own https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxTcP.jpg

Comment: You should use the `Shader Editor for this. 
https://imgur.com/a/uNc9VkH

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to select all the top vertices, you could **select all the others** and just **invert the selection**.

Since the lateral geometries seems to me more regular than the top one, they should be easier to select.

Select one of the lateral faces, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (Select similar) then choose `Normal`. Or go to `Select`>`Select Similar`>`Normal`

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

You may adjust the Threshold if the faces' normals are not perfectly aligned.

Repeat that process for the 4 other faces and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection.